# How to get last wednesday for current month in python?

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, python-datetime, timedelta

my code as follows

```
today = todayte
print('today1 =', today)
offset = (today.weekday() - 2) % 7
print('offset1=', offset)
last_wednesday = today - timedelta(days=offset)            
print('last_wednesday1 = ', last_wednesday)
```

my current output as follows

```
today1 = 2018-03-05
offset1 = 5
last_wednesday1 =  2018-02-28
```

in the above case i am getting **previous month last wednesday**
but i **need current month last wednesday.**

my expected output is as follows

```
last_wednesday = 2018-03-28
```

Comment: Generic algorithm: get the first Wednesday for the month+1, then subtract 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```py
from datetime import datetime , timedelta

todayDT = datetime.today()
currentMonth = todayDT.month

nWed = todayDT
while todayDT.month == currentMonth:
    todayDT += timedelta(days=1)
    if todayDT.weekday()==2: #this is Wednesday 
        nWed = todayDT
print (nWed)
```

Comment: i tried above code but i am getting following error                                                 
  ```Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\nifty_banknifty\banknifty_nifty_2018\bnf_nf_2018.py", line 141, in <module>
    todayDT += timedelta(days=1)

OverflowError: date value out of range```     @Adedoyin Akande

Comment: Just edited it, there was a typo

Comment: now the above code is working i get ```nWed=  2018-03-28 00:00:00``` this output. How i can seprate ```2018-03-28``` from above datetime object ?  @Adedoyin Akande   @AdedoyinAkande

Comment: i got it !!!  when i do ```nWed = nWed.date()``` i get ```nWed=  2018-03-28``` this date seprated . Thanks !!!

Comment: Great! You can also upvote the answer :winks

Comment: also i forgot to ask a question i am appending this last wednesday date to dataframe but i am getting an empty dataframe i am not able to understand why this is happening?  @Adedoyin Akande

Comment: https://code.labstack.com/python to share the full code so there is context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240194/discussion-between-shubham-birhade-and-adedoyin-akande).      @Adedoyin Akande

Comment: Where in the code are you specifying that it's the last Wednesday in the month, and how would you amend it for picking 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th specifically?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a combination of datetime and calendar modules:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import calendar

today = datetime.now()
# find first day of the month and then, find first wednesday of the month and replace it
# weekday of wednesday == 2
first_day = datetime.today().replace(day=1)
while first_day.weekday() != 2:
    first_day += timedelta(days=1)

number_of_days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(today.year, today.month)[1]
last_wend = first_day + timedelta(days=(((number_of_days_in_month - first_day.day) // 7) * 7))

print(last_wend)
```

or as [@Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) suggested:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

day_ = (datetime.now().replace(day=1) + timedelta(days=32)).replace(day=1)
while True:
    day_ -= timedelta(days=1)
    if day_.weekday() == 2:
        break
print(day_)
```

Comment: Thanks for running with my suggestion.  It's not quite the way I would have done it though, I hate iterating when a little simple math can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, we first jump to the next month and re-use your existing code:

```
import datetime as dt

todayte = dt.date(2018, 3, 5)
today = todayte
d = dt.date(today.year, today.month, 28) # the 28th day of a month must exist
d = d + dt.timedelta(days=7) # so we are sure d is in the next month
# then we apply your original logic
offset = (d.weekday() - 2) % 7
last_wednesday = d - dt.timedelta(days=offset)
print(last_wednesday)
```

Result:

```
2018-04-04
```

Comment: i tried above code i am getting following error                                                                                   
                                                                                                                           
 ```Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "E:\nifty_banknifty\banknifty_nifty_2018\bnf_nf_2018.py", line 136, in <module>
    d = d + dt.timedelta(days=7) # so we are sure d is in the next month

AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'```  @AlexKong @Alex Kong

Comment: you need to take care of the import, if you copy and paste my code to a new file, it should work--as I can get the right result.